# how to add dll properly to a .net c# blazor project

Tags: c#, dll, blazor, blazor-server-side, publishing

I am trying to publish a .NETCORE blazor server side project on a QA server
Everything work good in my local machine but when i publish my project, when i click the buton i need, it give me : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. exeption.

when i debug and log step by step i see that it come from a ligne where i use a dll that i found there[ExcelToObjectConvertor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1235693/Extract-NET-Object-from-Excel-WorkSheet?msg=5806752#xx5806752xx), i downloaded it and put it in my root/Ressources folder. Here is how i use it and it work good again in my local machine when i start in visual studio i get my dataToUpdatesList -> OK

```
string filePath1 = Path.GetFullPath(@"wwwroot/Ressources/ProduitsTEST.xls");
List<WorkSheetInfo> workSheetList = ExcelXMLConvertor.GetWortSheetsInfo(filePath1);
WorkSheetInfo workSheet = workSheetList.Find(wh => wh.WorkSheetName == @"Products");
dataToUpdatesList = ExcelXMLConvertor.GetObjectList<StocklineDataToUpdate>(workSheet.WorkSheetId);
```

But when i publish the project its not working... the -> workSheetList is NULL

i saw the file i need when i loop like this

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"wwwroot/Ressources");
foreach (string file in files)
   Log.Error(Path.GetFileName(file));
```

and i know that workSheetList is NULL cause

```
 if (workSheetListTS_Association == null)
       {
         Log.Error("NULLLLLLLL");
       }
```

Comment: At the very least it's `Resources`, not `Ressources`.

Comment: where @Blindy ..? i don't see that

Comment: Read your question, you wrote it wrong three times.

Comment: Sorry i dont see ... i made a ctlr F to search what you said but dont find mistake with "Resources" that you told me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem wasnot caused by the dll adding so i can answer myself how i did it

1-right click on your project
2-click Add -> Project Reference...
3-click on Browse and select your dll

More details here
[how to add DLL to your project](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/creating-and-using-dll-class-library-in-C-Sharp/#:%7E:text=Using%20DLL%20File-,Step%201%20%2D%20Open%20Visual%20Studio%20then%20select%20%22File%22%20%2D,%22%2C%20that%20we%20created%20earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

If the workSheetList object is null, I don't think it's a DLL problem - that would throw an Exception for a missing assembly. Is your "produitsTEST.xls" file on your QA server, and at the FilePath you specify? I would check that first.

I would also throw in some error handling in the event that workSheetList does come back as NULL.

Comment: Yes i double check the path and the file .... thanks for your answer @John Muraski maybe you'r right about that is not a dll problem but i dont know then why its not working cause the filePath1 is correct ... i write on the log a loop on the folder and i find the file there .... what do you mean for handling error ?

Comment: This might be more of a personal preference, but when I import documents like an Excel or CSV file, I wrap it in a  Try/Catch block. If reading the file comes back as NULL, I have it throw a custom exception. For example:

Comment: 'Try { //Read file if{File Read is Null, throw Exception} Catch(Exception){//Do Something}